# Unable to save data to Entity Model Database using saveChanges() method

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, insert, sql-update

I am trying to save data to my database. What I want is that when the button is pressed, data is saved to the database permanently. I've done tests where code is saved while the application is running. The saved data is viewable. But when I terminate the application, the data is not present when I view the data for that table in visual studio. I've provided the code that I am using for testing.

```
private void btn_otrFun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblCheese cheese = new tblCheese();
        string cheesename = "TestCheese";
        cheese.CheeseName = cheesename;
        cheese.CheeseGroup = 1;
        cheeseEntity.tblCheese.AddObject(cheese);
        cheeseEntity.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is where I am getting the context form. It is instantiated at the beginnning of the form.

```
 private CheeseWorld_DatabaseEntities cheeseEntity = new CheeseWorld_DatabaseEntities(); //instanciate new database entities
```

And further I am using this snippet to retrieve data from the the database to dynamically created buttons.

```
var cheeselist = cheeseEntity.ExecuteStoreQuery<tblCheese>("Select * FROM tblCheese WHERE cheeseGroup = 1", null).ToList();
```

Hope these further details help. If more are required, let me know.

Comment: Try returning an `int` with the number of rows affected:  `int rows = cheeseEntity.SaveChanges()` to ensure you are indeed updating the table.  Also you may want to set your `SaveOptions` parameter to `AcceptAllChangesAfterSave`.

Comment: perhaps it's a problem with your mouse?

Comment: Taking Evan's advice, i changed the last line to 
int rows = cheeseEntity.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave); 
The change still did not show up in the database. When I view table data for tblcheese, the entries that I previously had are already there, but the new one is not. Although, within the application it appears. This is what's confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

You've departed from the normal pattern we usually use for this... maybe try putting it back to something like this... (I don't see where you are getting the context)

```
using (var context = new cheeseEntity()) {
    tblCheese cheese = new tblCheese();
    cheese.CheeseName = "TestCheese";
    cheese.CheeseGroup = 1;
    context.tblCheese.Add(cheese);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is covered in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593489
 (Pay attention to the bottom where it shows how to trace the generated SQL)

*NOTE: I am using Add instead of AddObject.*

Comment: I was just about to post that myself, I was curious where the context was being created.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this is part of an ASP.Net application, and if the context is a local variable or something, I don't think it will be persisted for the event. This should result in a NullReference exception though, so it doesn't explain the behavior he's seeing.

Comment: Jasmine,I tried it your way. I do not get the add method. Instead I get a message that no definition exists for 'Add'. I changed is back to addObject and it works. But just like before the problem still is the same. 
As for the the context, I was getting that from a previous statement at the beginning of the form. I called the context cheeseEntity. If you assumed cheeseEntity was the database name, I'm sorry for causing the confusion.

Comment: Yeah you're using a funny naming convention and it's hard to tell what the types are in your code sample. If you don't have the Add method, that's a big sign you're working with the wrong type of object.

Comment: The way it's written in your sample, you have two different types of things called "tblCheese" - one is your object and the other is your collection. When you depart from the naming convention the standard that lets us tell those apart hasn't been implemented. Normally you have objects called "Cheese" and a collection called "Cheeses"

Comment: I'll keep the naming convention in mind for next time, but for now let me explain the current snippet's sense. 'CheeseEntity' is the context name. 'tblCheese' is the name of the table in the database. 'cheeseName' and 'cheeseGroup' are the names of the columns of the table. Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: OK, that helps, but what's really confusing me is when you create a new OBJECT called tblCheese. Remember, EF is an object-relational mapping framework, where rows in the database map to objects in your collection. TblCheese represents the collection of objects, not a single object, and CheeseName and CheeseGroup are properties of the objects (rows) not of the collection(table). So, you have two things named tblCheese - the object(row) and the collection(table). So what I'm saying is, I think when you do "new tblCheese" that's not the right object type.

Comment: I've seen other examples where they've used similar code for the table. I mean 'tblcheese cheese = new tblcheese();'. I tried a different format 'var cheese = new tblcheese();'. That did not help either. I don't understand why the data is only inserted on runtime and reverts back when application is closed. If that could be found, it would also help.

Comment: I think it's not saving to the database because you're saving the object to some context which isn't connected to the database, you're saving the object to the wrong collection, or the object you're saving is the wrong type. When you do that, it creates a spot in memory for it, but it has no idea how to save it to the database - that method is a no-op, so it doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't do anything. I think you need to put more code in your question - like, everything having to do with this. I still don't see where you are creating the context object.

Comment: Jasmine, I've added two more snippets from the code. I've added the code where I am getting the context from and the one where I am using this data entry. Hope that helps in understanding the problem a little bit more. I appreciate the time and effort you are spending in helping me.

Comment: Jasmine, I've figured out the problem. There was nothing wrong with the code at all. Apparently when you work with local databases, Visual Studio will create a copy and place in the \bin folder and use that while run time. Since the property was set to always copy, it was taking my database and rewriting it therefore erasing the data that has been added. 
I figured it would something simple that I was overlooking, turns out my hunch was right. Once again I appreciate your time and effort in to helping me. Here is the link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx

Comment: OK that's kinda what I thought, it was saving but not to the same place you were checking.